# How to Rank Dates Based on Other Column

Tags: spotfire

Does anyone know how to rank specified dates based on other column? I have this dilemma where I use Rank(RowId()"asc",(WellName) and the rank does not give me the first date.

[Rank Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0U6.png)

The rank should give me the first date not an arbitrary date. Please help if you know the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your screenshot, as all dates do appear ordered and there is only one value of WellName.

If what you want is to sort Date for every WellName, try this

DenseRank([Date],[WellName])